# Casing of FHIR resource names in URLs

Tags: hl7-fhir

As documented [here](http://www.hl7.org/fhir/stu3/http.html#general), the guidance when constructing FHIR URLs is that they are recommended to be case sensitive and that it is up to the implementers to define their behavior.

In that context, is there any specific requirement for resource names in URLs to be Pascal cased or is that also something that implementers can decide?

Answer (score 1):

The resource names are expected to be the same as they're defined in the specification.  E.g. "CodeSystem".  While servers are allowed to accept "codesystem", "cOdEsYsTeM", "CODESYSTEM", etc. any system that requests those is non-compliant.

Comment: Thanks Lloyd. It would be great if there was a reference to this in the FHIR spec. I remember coming across the pascal casing requirement in the earlier DSTU2 spec but I can no longer find it. Perhaps I am mistaken or have missed it?